# How do I make a button change its step after some point without losing value?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm looking to create a button on a webpage that will start having a step of "2" after a certain value.
The JS framework I'm using for the moment is vue.js and here is what I have so far:

```
<input :step="something >= 5 ? 2 : 1" type="number" >
```

the : before step is a shorthand for v-bind in vue.js.
Now my problem is that once I'm at the value of 5 the step down will be 2 as well, when I want the user to be able to choose 4 without having to go through value 3 then 4.

Alternatively I think I could generate an array of numbers, but I do not know how to introduce a step of 2 in the process.
Something like this [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13...]

Comment: That's sortof misusing the `step` attribute, and I don't think you'll be able to do what you want without some fragile, hacky code. You could create a custom component to do something similar without using an input element, but otherwise I don't think there's going to be a good solution.

Comment: I see, I think I was looking at the problem in the wrong way. I should simply create two arrays, one with a step of 1 and the other with a step of 2 and join them together.
Thank you for replying so quickly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this programmatically.

Updated to use a watch and also manage 'editing' mode so we alter the value while typing.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input :step="1" type="number" v-model="something" @keydown="keydown" />
    {{ editing }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
      something: 0,
      last: 0,
      editing: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    keydown(e) {
      this.editing = e.key !== "Enter";
      if (!this.editing) {
        this.validateSomething(Number(this.something));
      }
    },
    validateSomething(v) {
      if (v > 5) {
        if (v % 2 === 0) {
          if (v > this.last) {
            this.something = v + 1;
          } else {
            this.something = v - 1;
          }
        }
      }
      this.last = this.something;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    something: function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal, oldVal);
      let v = Number(newVal);
      if (!this.editing) {
        this.validateSomething(v);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here's a working codesandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/mm6x3q60px

Comment: The only thing here: what if the user wants to manually input a number? If I try to type in 81 it first changes 8 to 9 before I'm finished typing.

Comment: I updated to use @change instead.  Sometimes I get a lag, though.  Still investigating...

Comment: In the category of really-need-to-manage-my-ocd, I updated it with a version that doesn't interfere with typing a number directly.

Comment: Thank you so much @JimB. This is super helpful. I still have a question though, if my button already has a different v-model, is there a way for me to still achieve this?

Comment: You should be able to use the same v-model.  `something` is just a placeholder.

Comment: @JimB. Would it be possible to simply bind the validateSomething method to the value with a v-bind to make the change automatically without having to press Enter?

Comment: I think the problem is that as you type you are going to type in numbers that need correction.  If you do that without waiting for enter, you'll correct a partially entered number.  You could do something with a timeout instead, but then you force the user to type quickly enough.  Just a design choice.